# google app engine NDB records counts from NDB model

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

How many records we can get from google app engine from single query so that we can display count to user and is we can increase timeout limit 3 seconds to 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, ndb cannot pull more than 1000 records at a time. Here is an example of what happens if I try to use `.count()` on a table that contains ~500,000 records.

```
s~project-id> models.Transaction.query().count()
WARNING:root:suspended generator _count_async(query.py:1330) raised AssertionError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py", line 160, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1287, in count
    return self.count_async(limit, **q_options).get_result()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 383, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 427, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1330, in _count_async
    batch = yield rpc
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 513, in _on_rpc_completion
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 614, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2910, in __query_result_hook
    self._batch_shared.conn.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1377, in check_rpc_success
    rpc.check_success()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 580, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 157, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 308, in MakeSyncCall
    handler(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 362, in _Dynamic_Next
    assert next_request.offset() == 0
AssertionError
```

To by pass this, you can do something like:

```
objs = []
q = None
more = True
while more:
    _objs, q, more = models.Transaction.query().fetch_page(300, start_cursor=q)
    objs.extend(_objs)
```

But even that will eventually hit memory/timeout limits.

Currently I use Google Dataflow to pre-compute these values and store the results in Datastore as the models `DaySummaries` & `StatsPerUser`

#### EDIT:

`snakecharmerb` is correct. I was able to use `.count()` in the production environment, but the more entities it has to count, the longer it seems to take. Here's a screenshot of my logs viewer where it took ~15 seconds to count ~330,000 records

[image]

When I tried adding a filter to that query which returned a count of ~4500, it took about a second to run instead.

#### EDIT #2:

Ok I had another app engine project with a kind with ~8,000,000 records. I tried to do `.count()` on that in my http request handler and the request timed-out after running for 60 seconds.

[image]

Comment: I think the 1000/AssertionError issue is confined to the remote shell - see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35893498.

Comment: You're correct. I updated my answer. But I still wonder about the scalability of `.count()`. It took ~1 second to count 4500 records, ~15 seconds to count 330,000 records. How long would it take to count 1 million and beyond.